# Web deployment using AWS Lightsail

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-lightsail

I'm new to deploying websites. I build a React frontend with a Django backend and a mysql database. I dockerized it and purchased a domain. Now I would like to bring it to production but the options seem endless.

I want to use AWS Lightsail but I am not sure whether to choose the containers or instances and what the difference is, containers are twice as expensive but what do you get for that money?

Also, is it possible to run a Mysql database in the Lightsail instance or container, or do I need to purchase a database seperately?

If anyone could explain this to my I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I am using [DeployHQ](https://www.deployhq.com/) to deploy my React app to AWS Lightsail for FREE.  I am not using Django, as I am using NodeJS but process should be the same.

1. Create server in DeployHQ, choose SSH
2. Add Lightsail instance public IP & username
3. Upload private key created for your Lightsail instance
4. Specify absolute path to your React build folder in 'Deployment Path' field; ex: martsmits/build
5. In 'Deployment Options' advanced settings, check box for Automatically deploy
6. Specify build/ folder in 'Subdirectory to deploy from' field
7. In AWS Lightsail instance, update Firewall to grant SSH access to the range of IPs that DeployHQ provides

Comment: Really helpful answer and clearly explained (for once!) - worked perfectly for me (even with slightly different requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, options are endless.
Considering you want to use AWS Lightsail and you have your backend and frontend services containerized.

You should have five containers running with docker -

1. Nginx Container
2. Certbot Container
3. Django Backend Container
4. React Frontend Container
5. MySQL database Container (Make sure to have the volume mounted to save your data)

The Nginx will work as a load balancer, You can use Let's encrypt and the Certbot will generate SSL certificates, which you will use for your service to expose via Nginx as a load balancer.

The Nginx will run on port 80, you have to put the IP address of your light sail in the DNS config of your domain. So once there's traffic comes to your instance, (you need to write an Nginx conf for your frontend service). then Nginx will forward it to your frontend service, the frontend service will use the Django backend, and the backend will use the Mysql database.

Put all the services in the same docker network with different ports. Use a docker-compose file to organize is easy.

Note: This is not recommended for production use. In short, that's all I can suggest, as you are new to deployment.

Comment: What is the amount of storage offered by the lightsail container service? The pricing page only shows cpu and memory. I have a python api running on lightsail container service. It's POST endpoint receives a file, stored it in temporary folder, processes the file, deletes the file and responds back with processed JSON. I am curious to know what is the disk space capacity of the lightsail container service.